# Why am I getting a syntax error on this else if statement?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I'm writing a code for a dice roll game and getting a weird syntax error.
The syntax error I get for the script below is: `invalid syntax: else:`
                                                                   ^

```
import random 
num = random.randint(1, 7)

def dice_roll():

    gold = 0
    input = ('Do you want to play again?' )
    if num == 2:
        gold = (gold + 2)

        print (gold)
        print ('You Win!')
        print (input)

        if input != ('yes'):
            dice_roll()


            else:
                print ('Loser')

dice_roll()
```

Does someone know why this code would give me such an error?

Answer (score 2):

Python is particular about indentation. Your else statement should have equal indentation as the above if-statement.

```
    if input != ('yes'):
        dice_roll()
    else:
        print ('Loser')
```

Answer (score 0):

Else must be aligned with if, that is, shift two last lines to the left so that "else" was right under if.

Comment: Thanks I got it working, and understand the theory a little better now.